# Audio to midi CC

Tags: software, midi

All.

I'm wondering if there's a VST (for example) that would take audio as input (containing monophonic playing) and produce "midi CC" (continuous stream) as output. This output would contain pitch and volume information that I could then feed into a midi synth.

I'm a trumpet player and that would allow me to use different sounds in my playing without any additional hardware (like for example one of these so called "EWI"), just my regular mic and instrument.

I've seen Chris Kase do this live in Madrid using a modern day "EWI" that produces midi CC as output and the result was pretty cool.

I kind of fancy getting my trumpet jazzy solo phrasing to sound like it's coming from one of these '80s analogue synths :-D

I mean, real time pitch detection seems not a technical challenge at all these days ("autotunes" indeed come as VST add-ons), and amplitude detection is no big deal as that's what vu-meters do.

Thoughts, pointers? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reatune plugin available with Reaper does this:

https://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/Use_Reatune_to_write_audio_to_midi

I believe this can also be used in real-time, although I've not tried it myself.

Comment: Magic, man! Precisely what I meant.

I've gone through the description in your link and yes, it looks like it does it in real time too :-)

Comment: Great stuff!  Let us know how you get on with it.

Comment: I can't believe how effortless it was to get it to work!!! :-O It's astonishing. I just followed the instructions in the link, chained up Reasynth using its defaults throughout (I didn't touch a single fader), added a little reverb to its output and got this!!!

https://mega.nz/file/6IwnHBRb#GTSSmKhsEUmJsUuJ6Ks0fONoT0WuN952q7KSTJlrnok

The possibilities are now endless!! Thanks!!

Comment: That's great!  Glad to help.  I've found the Reaper plugins very good myself.  There are some good tutorial videos, including plugins, on their website which may provide some inspiration: https://www.reaper.fm/videos.php

Comment: (Just a note that the link on my previous comment is no longer valid, please use this instead: https://mega.nz/file/vBJjTQjT#yEbrkWy4HyJnXD6B6Fm5fJlhkMvS0Z8V2sil_zdtvHg )